# The link is also opening in the window as well as in popup

Tags: javascript

```
window.onclick = function(e) { var url = e.target;
windowObjectReference = window.open(
    url,
    "DescriptiveWindowName",
    "resizable,scrollbars,status"
  );
};
```

// I am trying to popup the clicked link but the page from where it is clicked is also changing. How to prevent it from changing?

Comment: use `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @CoolJK Thanks ... It worked like charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to stop the normal event behaviour from firing when clicking:

```
    window.onclick = function(e) { var url = e.target;
    windowObjectReference = window.open(
        url,
        "DescriptiveWindowName",
        "resizable,scrollbars,status"
      );
      e.preventDefault();//just add this line
    };
```